# Parameter Optimization in RF and rpart

Tags: r, optimization, random-forest, parameterization, rpart

I am using rpart and random forest in R to predict GPA (regression tree). On what basis do I decide the value of cp, minsplit, and minbucket? And on what basis do I decide the values of mtry and ntree for the random forest?

My dataset is 3000x10 which means there are 3000 observations, 9 independent variables, and 1 dependent variable (GPA).

I also ran the following code:

```
minsplit <- seq(5, 20, 1)
maxdepth <- seq(8, 15, 1)

#Generate a search grid
hyperparam_grid <- expand.grid(minsplit = minsplit, maxdepth = maxdepth)

#No. of potential models in the grid
num_models <- nrow(hyperparam_grid)

#Create an empty list
girls_models <- list()

#Set up a for loop to automate the modeling
for (i in 1:nrow(hyperparam_grid)) {
  
  # get minsplit, maxdepth values at row i
  minsplit <- hyperparam_grid$minsplit[i]
  maxdepth <- hyperparam_grid$maxdepth[i]

  # train a model and store in the list
  girls_models[[i]] <- rpart(
    formula = GPA ~ WJ10 + Grit + PCG_Income + PCG_Education + IPC + P_AI + PW + PCG_CC + AM,
    data    = ffc.girl1_train,
    method  = "anova",
    control = list(minsplit = minsplit, maxdepth = maxdepth)
    )
}

#Function to get optimal cp
get_cp <- function(x) {
  min    <- which.min(x$cptable[, "xerror"])
  cp <- x$cptable[min, "CP"] 
}

# function to get minimum error
get_min_error <- function(x) {
  min    <- which.min(x$cptable[, "xerror"])
  xerror <- x$cptable[min, "xerror"] 
}

hyperparam_grid <- hyperparam_grid %>%
  mutate(
    cp    = purrr::map_dbl(girls_models, get_cp),
    error = purrr::map_dbl(girls_models, get_min_error)
    ) %>%
  arrange(error) %>%
  top_n(-5, wt = error)

#Check model:
optimal_girls <- rpart(
  formula = GPA ~ WJ10 + Grit + PCG_Income + PCG_Education + IPC + P_AI + PW + PCG_CC + AM,
  data = ffc.girl1_train,
  method = "anova",
  control = list(minsplit = 20, maxdepth = 13, cp =0.01)
)
```

Sample data:

```
dput(head(df,20))

structure(list(Gender = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), WJ10 = structure(c(98, 97.9222255459168, 
97.9222255459168, 92, 102, 97.9222255459168, 117, 97.9222255459168, 
82, 97.9222255459168, 96, 78, 106, 122, 98, 103, 98, 86, 97, 
103), label = "Woodcock Johnson Test 10 standard score", format.stata = "%18.0g", labels = c(`-9 Not in wave` = -9, 
`-8 Out of range` = -8, `-7 N/A` = -7, `-6 Skip` = -6, `-5 Not asked` = -5, 
`-4 Multiple ans` = -4, `-3 Missing` = -3, `-2 Don't know` = -2, 
`-1 Refuse` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), Grit = c(3, 3.42277664630007, 3.42277664630007, 3.75, 
3.75, 3.42277664630007, 3.5, 3.42277664630007, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
3.75, 3.5, 4, 2.5, 3.25, 4, 3.25), Selfcontrol = c(3.8, 2.9086858882956, 
2.9086858882956, 2.9086858882956, 3, 2.9086858882956, 2.7, 2.9086858882956, 
1.1, 2.9086858882956, 2.8, 2.9086858882956, 2.9086858882956, 
3, 1.78847016599372, 2.5, 2.6, 2.9086858882956, 3.3, 2.9086858882956
), Attention = c(3, 2.6345624411902, 2.6345624411902, 2.5, 2.8, 
2.6345624411902, 2.7, 2.6345624411902, 1.3, 2.6345624411902, 
2.7, 2.9, 2.8, 3, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.4, 3, 2.9), PCG_Income = structure(c(1e+05, 
60643.8736017897, 60643.8736017897, 10000, 24000, 60643.8736017897, 
3e+05, 60643.8736017897, 165000, 90000, 7923, 26000, 24000, 68000, 
65000, 2e+05, 33308, 80000, 2856, 27600), label = "Constructed - PCG's household income (with imputed values)", format.stata = "%15.0g", labels = c(`-9 Not in wave` = -9, 
`-8 Out of range` = -8, `-7 N/A` = -7, `-6 Skip` = -6, `-5 Not asked` = -5, 
`-4 Multiple ans` = -4, `-3 Missing` = -3, `-2 Don't know` = -2, 
`-1 Refuse` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), PCG_Education = structure(c(2, 2.63777089783282, 
2.63777089783282, 2, 1, 2.63777089783282, 4, 2.63777089783282, 
3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3), label = "Constructed - PCG's education: year 15", format.stata = "%18.0g", labels = c(`-9 Not in wave` = -9, 
`-8 Out of range` = -8, `-7 N/A` = -7, `-6 Skip` = -6, `-5 Not asked` = -5, 
`-4 Multiple ans` = -4, `-3 Missing` = -3, `-2 Don't know` = -2, 
`-1 Refuse` = -1, `1 less HS` = 1, `2 HS or equiv` = 2, `3 Some coll, tech` = 3, 
`4 coll or grad` = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), IPC = c(NA, 0.00864548759285601, 0.00864548759285601, 
NA, NA, 0.00864548759285601, NA, 0.00864548759285601, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), P_AI = c(3.5, 2.89188260698861, 
2.89188260698861, 3, 3, 2.89188260698861, 3.5, 2.89188260698861, 
3.33333333333333, 3.5, 4, 2.5, 3, 3, 3, 2.66666666666667, 2, 
2, 4, 2.66666666666667), PW = c(4, 2.87519700551615, 2.87519700551615, 
3, 4, 2.87519700551615, 3, 2.87519700551615, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2.5, 
2.5, 2.33333333333333, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 3), PCG_CC = c(1, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 
2.5, 2.5), AM = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GPA = c(3.5, 3, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 3, 3.25, 
3.5, 3, 2.75, 2.75, 4, 2.75, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 2.75)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
> dput(head(ffc.girl1,20))
structure(list(Gender = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), WJ10 = structure(c(97.9222255459168, 
114, 97.9222255459168, 95, 97.9222255459168, 97.9222255459168, 
97.9222255459168, 117, 112, 89, 114, 97.9222255459168, 85, 88, 
97.9222255459168, 97.9222255459168, 97.9222255459168, 76, 88, 
86), label = "Woodcock Johnson Test 10 standard score", format.stata = "%18.0g", labels = c(`-9 Not in wave` = -9, 
`-8 Out of range` = -8, `-7 N/A` = -7, `-6 Skip` = -6, `-5 Not asked` = -5, 
`-4 Multiple ans` = -4, `-3 Missing` = -3, `-2 Don't know` = -2, 
`-1 Refuse` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), Grit = c(2.75, 4, 3.42277664630007, 4, 4, 3.42277664630007, 
3.42277664630007, 3, 4, 3.5, 3.25, 3.42277664630007, 3.25, 3.5, 
3.5, 3.42277664630007, 4, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75), Selfcontrol = c(2.9086858882956, 
3.7, 2.9086858882956, 2.9, 2.9086858882956, 2.9086858882956, 
2.9086858882956, 3.2, 2.4, 2.5, 2.9086858882956, 2.9086858882956, 
2.9086858882956, 2.9086858882956, 2.1, 2.9086858882956, 2.9086858882956, 
2.9086858882956, 2.9086858882956, 2.1), Attention = c(2.6345624411902, 
2.2, 2.6345624411902, 2.9, 2.6345624411902, 2.6345624411902, 
2.6345624411902, 2.9, 3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.6345624411902, 2.9, 2.9, 
3, 2.6345624411902, 2.6345624411902, 2.9, 2.5, 3), PCG_Income = structure(c(106285, 
49000, 60643.8736017897, 28505, 120000, 60643.8736017897, 60643.8736017897, 
105000, 120236, 14000, 40000, 60643.8736017897, 14449, 42000, 
26000, 60643.8736017897, 56000, 14020, 29000, 2989), label = "Constructed - PCG's household income (with imputed values)", format.stata = "%15.0g", labels = c(`-9 Not in wave` = -9, 
`-8 Out of range` = -8, `-7 N/A` = -7, `-6 Skip` = -6, `-5 Not asked` = -5, 
`-4 Multiple ans` = -4, `-3 Missing` = -3, `-2 Don't know` = -2, 
`-1 Refuse` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), PCG_Education = structure(c(3, 2, 2.63777089783282, 
3, 4, 2.63777089783282, 2.63777089783282, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2.63777089783282, 
2, 2, 3, 2.63777089783282, 4, 3, 3, 3), label = "Constructed - PCG's education: year 15", format.stata = "%18.0g", labels = c(`-9 Not in wave` = -9, 
`-8 Out of range` = -8, `-7 N/A` = -7, `-6 Skip` = -6, `-5 Not asked` = -5, 
`-4 Multiple ans` = -4, `-3 Missing` = -3, `-2 Don't know` = -2, 
`-1 Refuse` = -1, `1 less HS` = 1, `2 HS or equiv` = 2, `3 Some coll, tech` = 3, 
`4 coll or grad` = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), IPC = c(0.00864548759285601, NA, 0.00864548759285601, 
NA, 0.00864548759285601, 0.00864548759285601, 0.00864548759285601, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.00864548759285601, NA, NA, NA, 0.00864548759285601, 
0.00864548759285601, NA, NA, NA), P_AI = c(2, 2, 2.89188260698861, 
4, 3, 2.89188260698861, 2.89188260698861, 3, 2, 2.5, 3, 2.89188260698861, 
2.5, 2, 2, 2.89188260698861, 2, 2.5, 3, 2.5), PW = c(1.33333333333333, 
4, 2.87519700551615, 4, 3, 2.87519700551615, 2.87519700551615, 
4, 1, 3.5, 2.5, 2.87519700551615, 2.5, 1, 2, 2.87519700551615, 
2.5, 3.5, 3, 2.5), PCG_CC = c(2, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 
1, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5), AM = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GPA = c(3, 
4, 3, 3.25, 3.75, 3, 3, 1.75, 3.25, 3.25, 4, 3, 2.5, 2.25, 2.75, 
3, 3.25, 2.25, 1.5, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
> dput(head(ffc.girl1_train, 20))
structure(list(Gender = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), WJ10 = structure(c(98, 97.9222255459168, 
97.9222255459168, 92, 102, 97.9222255459168, 117, 97.9222255459168, 
82, 97.9222255459168, 96, 78, 106, 122, 98, 103, 98, 86, 97, 
103), label = "Woodcock Johnson Test 10 standard score", format.stata = "%18.0g", labels = c(`-9 Not in wave` = -9, 
`-8 Out of range` = -8, `-7 N/A` = -7, `-6 Skip` = -6, `-5 Not asked` = -5, 
`-4 Multiple ans` = -4, `-3 Missing` = -3, `-2 Don't know` = -2, 
`-1 Refuse` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), Grit = c(3, 3.42277664630007, 3.42277664630007, 3.75, 
3.75, 3.42277664630007, 3.5, 3.42277664630007, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
3.75, 3.5, 4, 2.5, 3.25, 4, 3.25), Selfcontrol = c(3.8, 2.9086858882956, 
2.9086858882956, 2.9086858882956, 3, 2.9086858882956, 2.7, 2.9086858882956, 
1.1, 2.9086858882956, 2.8, 2.9086858882956, 2.9086858882956, 
3, 1.78847016599372, 2.5, 2.6, 2.9086858882956, 3.3, 2.9086858882956
), Attention = c(3, 2.6345624411902, 2.6345624411902, 2.5, 2.8, 
2.6345624411902, 2.7, 2.6345624411902, 1.3, 2.6345624411902, 
2.7, 2.9, 2.8, 3, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.4, 3, 2.9), PCG_Income = structure(c(1e+05, 
60643.8736017897, 60643.8736017897, 10000, 24000, 60643.8736017897, 
3e+05, 60643.8736017897, 165000, 90000, 7923, 26000, 24000, 68000, 
65000, 2e+05, 33308, 80000, 2856, 27600), label = "Constructed - PCG's household income (with imputed values)", format.stata = "%15.0g", labels = c(`-9 Not in wave` = -9, 
`-8 Out of range` = -8, `-7 N/A` = -7, `-6 Skip` = -6, `-5 Not asked` = -5, 
`-4 Multiple ans` = -4, `-3 Missing` = -3, `-2 Don't know` = -2, 
`-1 Refuse` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), PCG_Education = structure(c(2, 2.63777089783282, 
2.63777089783282, 2, 1, 2.63777089783282, 4, 2.63777089783282, 
3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3), label = "Constructed - PCG's education: year 15", format.stata = "%18.0g", labels = c(`-9 Not in wave` = -9, 
`-8 Out of range` = -8, `-7 N/A` = -7, `-6 Skip` = -6, `-5 Not asked` = -5, 
`-4 Multiple ans` = -4, `-3 Missing` = -3, `-2 Don't know` = -2, 
`-1 Refuse` = -1, `1 less HS` = 1, `2 HS or equiv` = 2, `3 Some coll, tech` = 3, 
`4 coll or grad` = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), IPC = c(NA, 0.00864548759285601, 0.00864548759285601, 
NA, NA, 0.00864548759285601, NA, 0.00864548759285601, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), P_AI = c(3.5, 2.89188260698861, 
2.89188260698861, 3, 3, 2.89188260698861, 3.5, 2.89188260698861, 
3.33333333333333, 3.5, 4, 2.5, 3, 3, 3, 2.66666666666667, 2, 
2, 4, 2.66666666666667), PW = c(4, 2.87519700551615, 2.87519700551615, 
3, 4, 2.87519700551615, 3, 2.87519700551615, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2.5, 
2.5, 2.33333333333333, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 3), PCG_CC = c(1, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 
2.5, 2.5), AM = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GPA = c(3.5, 3, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 3, 3.25, 
3.5, 3, 2.75, 2.75, 4, 2.75, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 2.75)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Are you aware of grid search? Can help you with this if you can provide a sample data set for your problem. You can use ```dput(head(df,20))``` for that where df is the data frame and 20 is the number of columns. This will help others easily reproduce your problem.

Comment: Aah, okay. I am going to try this. Otherwise, I will post the problem here.

Comment: @Shibaprasadb I ran the grid search. What I do not understand is that how do I choose the parameters. How do I choose the range of cp, min split, minbucket, and maxdepth? So for instance when I plot the tree with the parameters, then what should be the value of cp, minbucket, and maxdepth? Is it possible to show an example?